# Copy-Paste Range Only with Values from Excel into Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have been using this site for some time and usually research all of my questions but this one has had me stumped for a few days.

I have an Excel workbook with sheets that will allow the user to input specific data, and once the macro is used will create a Word doc formatted specifically for each macro.

I am trying to copy a range from excel but not all rows will be completed. The Range is currently 25 rows but most users will only use 8-12:

```
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet4.Name).Range("A8:D33")
```

I can copy this range and paste it into Word as a table but I am getting the empty rows as well. In Excel I would simply .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues but this is not compatible with Word formatting.

Below is my current code to copy the range into my Word document:

```
With Doc.Paragraphs(21).Range
    tbl.Copy
    Doc.Paragraphs(21).Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False
    '.PageSetup.LeftMargin = "40"
    '.PageSetup.RightMargin = "40"

    Set wtbl = Doc.Tables(1)
    wtbl.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
    wtbl.Borders.Enable = True
        With wtbl.Rows(1)
            .Height = 10
            .Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalBottom
        End With
    'wtbl.Rows.Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalBottom
    'wtbl.Rows.Height = 15

    'Doc.Paragraphs(23).AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

End With
```

Comment: Please disregard the few sections that have been commented out. They do not work, and are for formatting once I get the table to populate the date I want. I will play with those areas later.

Comment: If "most users will only use 8-12" why don't you just dynamically size the Excel range instead?

Comment: I apologize, I do not know what you mean by dynamically size the range? I need to allow up to 25 rows because there are one off scenarios that will require that many

Comment: I mean, figure out how many rows you need to copy, and then just copy those rows. There's nothing that says `.Range("A8:D33")` needs to be hard-coded.

Comment: It will vary each time. The user uses this sheet per letter generation, so one may require 8 rows, the next may require 15. This macro is used each time they generate a new word doc

Comment: That's my point.  If the size of the `Range` will vary each time, then vary the size of the `Range` each time.  Right now you have it hard-coded.

Comment: I am sorry, I may not be explaining this correctly. This excel doc is going to be used by multiple users throughout their day, so it needs to be hard coded. I cannot change the range each time a user uses it.

Comment: Why not? It's a lot easier to find empty rows to ignore in Excel than delete them after the fact in Word.

Comment: How would I change the code for 18 users 5 days a week each using the tool 20-25 times each day?

Comment: You don't.  You change the code to figure out what ***needs to be copied*** instead of ***always*** copying `.Range("A8:D33")`.

Comment: That has been my question from the beginning. How do I do that?

Comment: Are rows entered in any specific order?  I.e., will all the blanks be at the bottom?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that as well. Ok, they will start as Cell A8 and complete the row until column D. So if a new row is used, all 4 columns will have values in that row. They will then move downward as they need

Comment: And yes, all blank rows will be at bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the last used cell in a column like this.  Assuming that all columns will have data in them and that the data entry is from row 8 moving down, this should do the trick:

```
With Sheet4
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(33, 1)).End(xlDown).Row
    Set tbl = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 4))
End With
```

Comment: I do have one last follow up question if you don't mind. I completely screwed up when I told you all the bottom rows would be blank. The final row (33) actually has 3 merged cells with the word "Total" and cell D33 sums all of column D. Is there a way to adapt your code so that it includes row 33?

Comment: I'd just copy everything *except* row 33  (`.Cells(32, 1)` instead of `.Cells(33, 1)`), and manually add the totals row afterward.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought of after I typed this, but I am struggling to get it to add it to the same table. This doesn't work:                                          With Sheet4
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(32, 1)).End(xlDown).Row
    Set tbl = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 4)) & .Range("A33:D33")
End With

Comment: @B.Price - Use `wtbl.Rows.Add` to add a row to the end of the table, then something like `wtbl.Cell(wtbl.Rows.Count, 1) = Sheet4.Cells(33, 1).Value` for A33, etc.

Comment: Ok thank you. That will get me started. I will start playing around with it. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Hi Comintern, I have been searching and playing with the code and I get the extra row added, but I keep getting an error . Can you take a quick look at this block of code and let me know how to modify the section that is commented out to add row 33?

Comment: With Doc.Paragraphs(21).Range
        tbl.Copy
        Doc.Paragraphs(21).Range.PasteExcelTable     LinkedToExcel:=False, 
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False
        Set wtbl = Doc.Tables(1)
        wtbl.Rows.Add
        'wtbl.Cell(wtbl.Rows.Count, 1) = Sheet4.Cells(33, 1).Value
        wtbl.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitContent)
        wtbl.Borders.Enable = True
            With wtbl.Rows(1)
                .Height = 10
                .Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalBottom
            End With
    End With

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to paste my code in the comment correctly. The error says Compile error: Invalid use of property and it is for this part: .Cell(wtbl.Rows.Count, 1) =

Comment: @B.Price - It should be `wtbl.Cell(wtbl.Rows.Count, 1).Range.Text = Sheet4.Cells(33, 1).Value`.

Comment: Thank you. That did it! No more questions, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that `CurrentRegion` is your friend:

```
Set tbl = Range("A8").CurrentRegion
```

If you get any extra columns you don't need, you can always use Resize property.